# CCSprite disappears for unknown reason

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

```
-(void)touchBegan:(UITouch*)touch withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInNode:self];
    [_gameBall setPosition:CGPointMake(touchPoint.x,self.gameBall.position.y)];
}
```

After a touch the _gameball sprite is not visible anymore, any reason why this happens?I logged it and isvisible for gameball is true and the touchpoint is always within the content size of my CCNode.

---

```
#import "GameScene.h"

@interface GameScene()

@property (nonatomic,strong) CCSprite* gameBall;

@end
@implementation GameScene

@synthesize gameBall = _gameBall;

+(GameScene*)gameInstance
{
    return [[self alloc]init];
}
-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        //Implement

        //user interaction
        self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

        //Create the ball
        _gameBall = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"small_blue_ball.png"];
        _gameBall.position = ccp(0.5f,0.1f);
        _gameBall.positionType = CCPositionTypeNormalized;
        [self addChild:_gameBall];


    }
    return self;
}
-(void)onEnter
{
    [super onEnter];
}
-(void)onExit
{
    [super onExit];
}
-(void)touchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInNode:self];
    touchPoint = [self convertToNodeSpace:touchPoint];
    [_gameBall setPosition:CGPointMake(touchPoint.x, self.gameBall.position.y)];
    NSLog(@"%f , %f",_gameBall.position.x,_gameBall.position.y);
}
-(void)touchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

}
@end
```

that was the .m file

now the .h file

```
#import "cocos2d-ui.h"
#import "cocos2d.h"

@interface IntroScene : CCScene
+(CCScene*)scene;
@end
```

Comment: Did you check touchPoint.x value?

Comment: Yes i did, i logged it and it shows valid data.

Comment: Use this : CGPoint location = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace: touch];

Comment: @shaqir. There is no convertTouchToNodeSpace just convertToNodeSpace.

Comment: I am getting this method with self. Can you please share both .h and .m file? What is the type of your file?

Comment: Just to make sure, the ball firstly appears on the screen and when you touch + reposition, it goes out of screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInNode:self];
touchPoint = [self convertToNodeSpace:touchPoint];
```

might be your problem..  try changing it to:

```
CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
touchPoint = [self convertToNodeSpace:touchPoint];
```

**-edit-**

ok, try:

```
CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
touchPoint = [[self parent] convertToNodeSpace:touchPoint];
```

**-edit2-**

just noticed the `cgpointmake`:

```
[_gameBall setPosition:CGPointMake(touchPoint.x, self.gameBall.position.y)];
```

might not do anything special, but you should keep your code monotone, as in if you used `_gameball.position` then also use `_gameball.position.y`

So might want to change it to:

```
_gameBall setPosition:CGPointMake(touchPoint.x, _gameBall.position.y)];
```

**-edit3-**

this seems to work for me:

```
CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
touchPoint = [[_gameBall parent] convertToNodeSpace:touchPoint];
[_gameBall setPosition:ccp(touchPoint.x, _gameBall.position.y)];
```

**-Final edit-**

Since you are using cocos2d, also use their ccTouchesBegan function.. Change it to:

```
-(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSArray* touchArray = [touches allObjects];
    for (UITouch* touch in touchArray)
    {
        CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
        touchPoint = [_gameBall convertToNodeSpace:touchPoint];
        [_gameBall setPosition:ccp(touchPoint.x, _gameBall.position.y)];
        break;
    }
}
```

if it doesn't register touches, then add: `[self setTouchEnabled:YES];` to your scene.

Comment: Same thing, its just disappearing after the touch.Its like its not getting redrawn at the new location.

Comment: try the second one and see if it works, cause I have a feeling that it goes out of screen while saying it's in the screen by point.

Comment: Ok now its not dissapearing but it seems to set the sprites X axis location to 0 and not the touchpoint x one.

Comment: Well then we are on the right track, because:
It means your code is not making it invisible, but placing it out of screen. Although I wonder why. Let me have a shot recreating this and ill be back in 5 mins.

Comment: If i use cpp(x,y) it doesnt go offscreen but i must use touchpoint coordinates.

Comment: real weird, cause it seems to work for me this way (edit 3), try it please

Comment: After changing [self parent] to [_gameball parent] it started disappearing again.

Comment: OK, and what delegate do i need to use in order to get that function get called every time a touch occurs?

Comment: did you set the setTouchEnabled?

Comment: I managed to make it work. Considering that cpp(0.5f,0.5f) works i tried calculating CGFloat pt = touchPoint.x/touch.view.frame.size.width; and set the new position like this [_gameBall setPosition:ccp(pt, _gameBall.position.y)]; Anyway thank you for your support, will accept your answer now.

Comment: Well, you're completely right there, I would have never thought about the scene being different in width. Which explains it all, happy that it works now anyways ^^